# GKE Autopilot scales up workload due to sidecar resource requests

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

GKE autopilot is adjusting my resource requests due to my sidecar container

```
autopilot.gke.io/resource-adjustment: {
  "input": {
    "containers": [
      {
        "limits": {
          "cpu": "30m",
          "memory": "100Mi"
        },
        "requests": {
          "cpu": "30m",
          "memory": "100Mi"
        },
        "name": "agones-gameserver-sidecar"
      },
      {
        "limits": {
          "cpu": "300m",
          "ephemeral-storage": "2Gi",
          "memory": "750Mi"
        },
        "requests": {
          "cpu": "300m",
          "ephemeral-storage": "2Gi",
          "memory": "750Mi"
        },
        "name": "websocket-server"
      }
    ]
  },
  "output": {
    "containers": [
      {
        "limits": {
          "cpu": "30m",
          "ephemeral-storage": "1Gi",
          "memory": "100Mi"
        },
        "requests": {
          "cpu": "30m",
          "ephemeral-storage": "1Gi",
          "memory": "100Mi"
        },
        "name": "agones-gameserver-sidecar"
      },
      {
        "limits": {
          "cpu": "470m",
          "ephemeral-storage": "2Gi",
          "memory": "750Mi"
        },
        "requests": {
          "cpu": "470m",
          "ephemeral-storage": "2Gi",
          "memory": "750Mi"
        },
        "name": "websocket-server"
      }
    ]
  },
  "modified": true
}
```

Is there any way to prevent this? I don't see why my cpu is being scaled up when I'm within the resource request limits.